# symfony2 doctrine query negation of where

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i wanna query for all of my categories like this:

```
$othercategories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:Category')->findBy(
  array('language' => $language, 'active' => 1),
  array('sorting' => 'ASC')
);
```

what i wanna do is to add another parameter to my query, i want all categories EXCEPT one with a specific id. so like:

```
WHERE id NOT IN ( 2 )
```

or

```
WHERE id <>  2
```

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DQL queries like this

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$query = $em->createQuery( 'SELECT c FROM Bundle:Category c WHERE c.language = :language AND c.active = 1 AND c.id NOT IN ( 2 ) ORDER BY c.language ASC' )
->setParameter('language', $language);

$category= $query->getResult();
```

Sorry I couldn't test this because I am using my phone to answer this question and I don't know your entity variables. Let me know what changes you did to make it work, it will help others.

For more info check http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/doctrine.html

You can add these queries in repository and reuse them. Refer the Cook book on http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/index.html

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax if you prefer

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Bundle:Category');
$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder();

$notInCategoryIds = array(2); // Category ids that will be excluded

$queryBuilder->select('c')
             ->from('Bundle:Category', 'c')
             ->where('c.language = :language')->setParameter('language', $language)
             ->andWhere('c.active = :active')->setParameter('active', 1)
             ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn('c.id', $notInCategoryIds)
             ->orderBy('c.sorting', 'ASC');

$results = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

It's probably going to be more useful for other developers that prefers this syntax